# An Application won't launch via Terminal or Desktop File

Tags: unity, chromebook

I am trying to launch the Linux beta version of Scrivener. I downloaded the .deb version, and tried to open it with GDebi Package Installer. However,the message `Error : Wrong Architecture 'amd64' appeared`. After that, I tried launching it via terminal with the command

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture scrivener-1.7.2.3-amd64.deb
```

When I hit enter, everything went fine and no error messages appeared. After that, I used gnome-panel to create a desktop file. Previously when I tried this, I was presented with another error message upon opening the desktop file. This time, I open it and nothing happens. I've tried opening it with terminal, but it reads `x error: unterminated quoted string` or `command not found`, depending on if I capitalize the name or not. In addition, opening the application by searching for it, or clicking on it from the launcher do not work either. I downloaded Linux Ubuntu with Unity on my hp chromebook 14-x23na. The downloading of the operating system went fine, until I tried opening the Scrivener application. All other applications work fine. Is this chromebook simply not compatible with this software?

Comment: Chromebooks have ARM CPUs, whose architecture is very different from  Intel/AMD x86/x86-64 CPUs. You can expect binary programs for one to work for the other.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the comment, to run software on chromeboook, you will need `arm` package. From the command I see you have package for `amd64`

You can find out what is your architecture (and packages you need) by running

```
jakuje@E6430:~$ uname -i
x86_64
```

DPKG will probably allow you to install packages with different architecture, but it will not work, as you see.